# CSS Hover Affect Children Only Not The Parent

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I want to change the `div` background color when hovering:

```
<div ng-show="collectionIsFocus">
    <div ng-if="collections" ng-repeat="c in collections">
        <div class="row collection-item">
            <div class="col-8 collection-item-col">
                <p>{{c.Name}}</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4 collection-item-col" ng-if="c.Image">
                <img src="{{c.Image.Url}}" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to change the background color for `<div class="row collection-item">`, but when I hover into it. The children `<div class="col-8 collection-item-col">` or `<div class="col-4 collection-item-col" ng-if="c.Image">` got the background color changed and the parent is not.

This is the css:

```
    .collection-item {
        cursor:pointer;
        height:50px;
        max-height:50px;
        overflow:hidden;
    }

    .collection-item :hover {
        background-color: lightblue;
    }

        .collection-item img {
            max-width: 100%;
            pointer-events: none !important;
        }

        .collection-item p {
            pointer-events: none !important;
            margin: 0;
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
            transform: translateY(-50%);
        }

        .collection-item .collection-item-col {
            height: 50px;
            max-height: 50px;
        }
```

My head hurts, this is so weird. Please help.

Comment: Remove the space between `.collection-item` and `:hover`. What you have now means "all hovered elements inside .collection-item" instead of ".collection-item when it is hovered".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.collection-item :hover {
    background-color: lightblue;
}
```

change this to(remove space between .collection-item and :hover)

```
.collection-item:hover {
    background-color: lightblue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, You should add change your code from:

```
.collection-item :hover {
    background-color: lightblue;
}
```

to

```
.collectionIsFocus .row :hover {
    background-color: lightblue !important;
}
```

Comment: But, I have written this code to a simple bootstrap page(without angularjs). It worked